# Process is running

Tags: shell-script, ps, pkill

I have run the following command as root today morning

```
 sh /home/suio/LoadSnortSingature.sh > /home/suio/logs.txt 2>&1
```

after some time the session of the terminal closed and I have relogged in again and did

```
 tail  -f /home/suio/logs.txt
```

it was stopped at certain point.After some time I blindly run again

```
sh /home/suio/LoadSnortSingature.sh
```

It says process is running, I have cross checked with ps and there was no process running this shell name and tried to kill using

```
 pkill -f  LoadSnortSingature.sh
```

but this didnot worked , I am still getting process is running message.I am using

```
Linux shio.jp 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 22 16:42:41 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

How to kill the process?

Comment: @Fox I performed the pkill as root.

Comment: Sorry When I went through the script I see they have locked the if [ -f ${LOCKFILE} ] ; then
    echo process is running
    exit 1  , I have cleared the lock file now I am able to run the script.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the script started some other processes which should have same ppid. Check zombies with

```
ps -elf | grep -v grep | grep Z
```

where Z is process your are looking for.

Then, sort processes by owner.